# Cannot invoke 'sequence' with an argument list of type '([AnyObject])'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I have upgraded to Xcode 7-beta and it gives me this error: Cannot invoke 'sequence' with an argument list of type '([AnyObject])'. That error is in this line of code:

```
sprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionarray as [AnyObject]))
```

I found that in swift 2 I must remove part of it and it must look like this:

```
sprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionarray))
```

But actionarray in NSMutableArray and now it gives me this error: Cannot invoke 'sequence' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableArray)'

This is the content of NSMutableArray:

```
var actionarray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
actionarray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, -sprite.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))
actionarray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())
sprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionarray))
```

It worked well in Xcode 6. What should I change there?

Thanks

Comment: What is the contents of your `actionarray`?  Where are you declaring it?  Are you sure it contains SKAction objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `NSMutableArray` in Swift code in the first place?
Try replacing with Swift array like this (compiles in Playground):

```
import Cocoa
import SpriteKit

let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
var actionarray: [SKAction] = []
actionarray.append(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointZero, duration: NSTimeInterval(1.0)))
actionarray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())
sprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionarray))
```

Comment: Check my edited reply. It compiles for me on beta 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax:

```
SKAction.sequence(actionarray as AnyObject as [SKAction])
```

Comment: Now the second error disappeared, but first is still there

Comment: that's strange, in my code I'm not passing `[AnyObject]` but `[SKAction]`